# Object Files Collision Solution is Failing for Managed C++ in VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, managed-c++

This question is an addition for [Visual Studio 2010's strange “warning LNK4042”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695174/visual-studio-2010s-strange-warning-lnk4042). Shortly, Visual Studio makes the following folders structure flat for generated C++ object files -> same name object files are overwritten -> which causes linker errors.

```
/FolderA/
  SameFileName.cpp
  SameFileName.h

/FolderB/
  SameFileName.cpp
  SameFileName.h
```

The solution is applying

```
$(IntDir)/%(RelativeDir)/
```

at VS C++ project option:
    C/C++ -> Output Files -> "Object File Name"

But this solution is failing for Managed C++ project. At last compilation step compiler generates file for managed project in temporal folder:

```
"C:\Users\my_name\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cpp"
```

which causes an error because of "/%(RelativeDir)/":

```
Error   35  error C1083: Cannot open compiler generated file: 'C:\Users\my_name\AppData\Local\Temp\/x86\Debug\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.obj': No such file or directory C:\Users\my_name\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cpp   1
```

This makes me a bit sad since I have to end up with ugly files' names which are unique. Maybe some of you had same problem and solved it more gracefully? Thx!

Comment: Windows is not Unix, use a backslash.

Comment: Thanks for comment :)