# Trouble with ofxFaceTracker (open frameworks) examples

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, openframeworks

I've been trying to get ofxFaceTracker (https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxFaceTracker) running for a few days now. I've installed ofxCv and the examples run correctly.

However, when I try to run the ofxFaceTracker examples, I get the following error messages:

> ContourFinder.obj: error LNK2019:? Unresolved external symbol "float __cdecl ofxCv :: trackingDistance (class cv :: Rect_  const &, class cv :: Rect_  const &)" (trackingDistance @ ofxCv @@ ? YAMABV $ Rect_ @ H @ cv @@ 0 @ Z) is a function "public: virtual class std :: vector > const & __thiscall ofxCv :: Tracker > :: track (class std :: vector , class std :: allocator >> const &) "(track @? $ Tracker @ V? $ Rect_ @ H @ cv @@@ ofxCv @@ UAEABV? $ vector @ IV? $ allocator @ I @ std @@@ std @@ ABV? $ vector @ V? $ Rect_ @ H @ cv @ @V? $ allocator @ V? $ Rect_ @ H @ cv @@@ std @@@ was referenced in 4 @@ Z).
>
> ObjectFinder.obj: error LNK2001:? External symbol "" float __cdecl ofxCv :: trackingDistance (class cv :: Rect_  const &, class cv :: Rect_  const &) "(trackingDistance @ ofxCv @@ YAMABV? $ Rect_ @ H @ cv @@ 0 @ Z) "is unresolved.

In short, its LNK2019 and LNK2001 error messages. I've done quite a bit of searching on the web concerning this issue and here's what I found.

The following websites all give the same solution to the problem, which is to replace  $(IntDir) with $(IntDir)/%(RelativeDir)/ in Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Output File -> Object File Name.

https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxFaceTracker/issues/115

[Visual Studio 2010 & 2008 can't handle source files with identical names in different folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729515/visual-studio-2010-2008-cant-handle-source-files-with-identical-names-in-diff)

[Visual Studio 2010's strange "warning LNK4042"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695174/visual-studio-2010s-strange-warning-lnk4042/3731643#3731643)

The problem is the C/C++ option isn't there for me. I've done more digging and found that the option only appears if you have a .cpp file in the project. The thing is, I haven't been able to add one to the project. Also, what bugs me is that according to this website (http://taka-say.hateblo.jp/entry/2016/02/24/200941 , sorry it's not in english, I used the basic Google Chrome page translator to translate it. Anyways, the images are what's important) When I do the exact same thing as the example and click on the example project in the Solution Explorer and then Properties, the only property that shows is Code Analysis. There's no C/C++ or any other option.

I'm running on Windows 8.1 64 bit, Visual Studio Community 2015, ofxFaceTracker 1.1 and the latest version of openFrameworks. I also get the projects into Visual Studio using the openFrameworks project generator.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, I had to completely uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio.